# How to plot a partial residual plot of a continuation ratio model in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a partial residual of a continuation ratio model in R.

I am using the following code:

```
load(url("http://www.produnis.de/R/OrdinalSample.RData"))
mydata <- ordinalSample
head(mydata)
require(VGAM)
cr <- vglm(Mood ~ JobFamily + JobSatisfaction, data=mydata, family=sratio(parallel=T,reverse=F));cr
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
plotvgam(cr,residuals=T)
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
dev.off()
```

Unfortunately, this gives me the following error message:

```
Warning: 
1: In vplot.numeric(x, ...) :   
ncol(residuals) != ncol(y) so residuals are not plotted 
2: In vplot.numeric(x, ...) :  
ncol(residuals) != ncol(y) so residuals are not plotted
```

I do not understand why this occurs and I am thankful for any advice on how to fix it...

I know how to plot a partial residual plot using the "`rms`" package with command `residuals.lrm(fit,type="partial",pl=T)`, unfortunately, this command won't work with vglm-fitted models...

Comment: Maybe contact the authors? Because `plotvglm`returns `stop("this function hasn't been written yet")` :(

Comment: Ìs there any chance to plot it "from scratch"? And how could I do so?...